# Почему usingElementComparatorIgnoringFields() используется для сравнения списков?

Tags: java, spring, junit, java-8

Разбираюсь с чужим кодом. Для тестирования используется `JUnit 5`. Для сравнения используется две таких функции:

```
(a, e) -> assertThat(a).usingRecursiveComparison().ignoringFields(fieldsToIgnore).isEqualTo(e);
(a, e) -> assertThat(a).usingElementComparatorIgnoringFields(fieldsToIgnore).isEqualTo(e);
```

Первая функция используется для сравнения единичных объектов, а вторая для сравнения `Iterable`, то есть для сравнения списков объектов. Я понимаю первую функцию. Вот тут: `usingRecursiveComparison()` мы задаём рекурсивное сравнение *(то есть сравнение по внутренним полям в том числе)*, а вот тут: `ignoringFields(fieldsToIgnore)` задаём игнорируемые в сравнении поля. Это мне понятно.

Я не понимаю вторую функцию. К сожалению, моего знания английского недостаточно для того, чтобы уловить разницу между `usingElementComparatorIgnoringFields(fieldsToIgnore)` и `usingRecursiveComparison().ignoringFields(fieldsToIgnore)`.

Вопрос в следующем: какая разница между двумя этими функциями и почему первая предназначена для сравнения одиночных объектов, а вторая для сравнения списков?

Answer (score 1):

1. В первом случае `usingRecursiveComparison()` используется рекурсивное сравнение объектов, то есть если в объекте есть вложенные объекты то компаратор будет рекурсивно спускаться по ним, игнорируя заданные в `ignoringFields()` поля
2. В случае `usingElementComparatorIgnoringFields` сравниваются только сами объекты, включая поля, но без рекурсивного спуска по полям объекта, игнорируя заданные поля

Comment: Ммм, вопрос тут скорее в том, что в контексте приложения usingElementComparatorIgnoringFields используется для сравнения списков с объектами. Впрочем, в документации я всё-таки нашёл момент, где говорилось о том, что этот метод может быть использован для сравнения списков.

Comment: Короче, просто странно, что у `usingRecursiveComparison()` нет перегруженного брата, который проверяет списки, из-за этого приходится использовать `usingElementComparatorIgnoringFields()`